# Sql injection

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! Как составить инъекцию, и вывести все записи в таблице, если запрос выглядит так:

```
"select * from users where login = '$login' and passord = '$password'"
```

при том, что значения не фильтруются и магические кавычки отключены.

Answer (score 1):

как-то так например. в поле логин вводим Admin' --  и запрос будет таким

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='Admin' -- ' AND pass='123'
```

Если вводить в поле пароль, то вводим 123' OR login='Admin' --

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='Admin' AND pass='123' OR login='Admin' --  '
```

Comment: А если подставлять значения в кавычках -> '$login', то любое значение переменной будет воспринято как текст и инъекции не получится?

Comment: получится инъекция. если логин и пароль не фильтруются от всякой дряни, то такая инъекция пройдет. И опять же таки, это за условия, если sql запрос именно такой. Я в своих скриптах такое никогда не использовал и не буду. Процесс авторизации я усложняю. И постоянно использую всевозможные фильтрации входящих данных, включая mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: это не пример моего кода)))) это вопрос в экзамене. просто я не баловался инъекциями никогда.